Change collision mask of object
In many game engines, objects have a collision mask. I believe it is defined by the vertices shown in edit mode. Does blender offer a way to give the objects a collision mask or change vertices and edges without changing the geometry itself. For example, when you apply a subdivison modifier to an object, the object gets transformed while the vertices remain as before without applying the subdivison modifier to the object itself.
Can I change, move, delete the vertices and edges, or give a new collision in some way in the same sense without chaning the geometry itself.


Just an information about the terminology in Blender: when you choose a modifier from the modifier menu to be used on an object, this is "adding a modifier". When you talk about "applying a modifier" this means to make its effect on the geometry permanent and remove the modifier. So, when "applying" a Subdivision Surface modifier, this definitely changes the vertices of the mesh. I just let you know because this sometimes leads to confusion in questions here when people not exactly know if the asker is talking about "adding" or "applying" a modifier.

But for your question: looking at yor example - if your question is, can the mesh shape be something else than a cube but still keep the subdivided result as it is now with the cube, then the answer is no. Because the subdivided shape is based on the cube, they are not independent from each other. The other question would be: why? For a game engine or in Blender? Do you need this collision shape for rigid body simulations in Blender? Because you do not mention what this is needed for. In rigid bodies you can change the collision shape. Or parent an object to a rigid body with different shape.

i think you would do this by creating another object (which is simplified), turn on  collision and parent your "render object" to that simplified object.

Could you clarify.. where is the collision mask to be used? Is that inside Blender, or intended for export?

The collision mask is to be used in a game engine.

I want to export the object into unity, and I want it to interact with other objects with the computing power usuage reduced, or I can make objects that are shaped differently interact with other objects in a custom onsistent way.
